Unable to locate submit button through selenium
I am trying to locate submit button using selenium but unable to do so through By.XPATH.
XPATH = '//\*\[@id="mat-dialog-4"\]/app-campaign-detail/div/div\[3\]/button\[2\]'

Code:
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, '//\*\[@id="mat-dialog-4"\]/app-campaign-detail/div/div\[3\]/button\[2\]').click()

HTML:
<div _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" class="campaign-edit-footer">
    <button _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" mat-button="" mat-dialog-close="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base" type="button">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Cancel</span>
        <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span>
        <span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
    </button>
    <button _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>
</div>

I have tried this:
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, '//\*\[@id="mat-dialog-4"\]/app-campaign-detail/div/div\[3\]/button\[2\]').click()


If those class names and type are unique to only one button then you could simply use dynamic xparh to Target that element.So the xpath should look something like below
//button[@class="btn btn-primary"]

Or 

//button[@type="submit"]

Edit : just noticed after you edited the description,use By.XPATH not By.ID

The problem is that your code is showing By.ID but you're passing an XPath. You need to use By.XPATH instead.
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="mat-dialog-4"\]/app-campaign-detail/div/div\[3\]/button\[2\]').click()

You're also escaping a lot of characters in your XPath that don't need to be escaped. It just makes it harder to read.
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-dialog-4"]/app-campaign-detail/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()

Having said that, there's a much simpler XPath you can use
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()=" Submit"]').click()

or also a CSS selector
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn-primary[type="submit"]').click()


Locate the element by By.XPATH (not By.ID)
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="mat-dialog-4"\]/app-campaign-detail/div/div\[3\]/button\[2\]').click()

